# How to extend Nginx config in elastic beanstalk (Amazon Linux 2) For .NET CORE PROJECT

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

Increasing client_max_body_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
How to extend Nginx config in elastic beanstalk (Amazon Linux 2)
I had created the following files and folder but still not working.

```
|-- .platform
| `-- nginx
| `-- conf.d
| `-- myconf.conf
```

My code is written in .NET core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including the config file to the project, then press right click on the file, go to properties, then in build action propperty select: Content; and into copy to output directory select copy always

like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qom22.png)